# C# External component has thrown an exception

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

Backend database: **Access**. There are unhandled exception crushing the application. I am trying to use Try/Catch/Finally, and play around the application to identify code error one at a time. There may be many places causing unhandled exceptions, but I guess some of them are similar issue. I just play around and fix where I found.

Here is the first place causing exception error. Let me explain how I got here. First, I click ChildForm1 buttonXYZ, and the query returns no record; Then I click parent form menustrip button and try to open ChildForm2. The error comes up at ChildForm2_Load line Cn.Open. Here is error screenshot.

What goes wrong, and how to fix it?

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCMIH.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1FyL.jpg)

```
     //First, I click ChildForm1 buttonXYZ, and the query returns no record
 private void buttonXYZ_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    
     try
     {
         Cn.Open();
         string sqlStr = "SELECT ......";
         adapt = new OdbcDataAdapter(sqlStr, Cn);
         dt = new DataTable();
         adapt.Fill(dt);
         dgvABC.DataSource = dt;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
         Cn.Close();
     }
    
 }
    
    
    
 //Then I click parent form menustrip button and try to open ChildForm2
 private void OpenChildForm2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (ActiveMdiChild != null)
         ActiveMdiChild.Close();
    
     ChildForm2 childForm2 = new ChildForm2();
     childForm2.MdiParent = this;
     childForm2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
     childForm2.Show();
 }
```

Comment: At a guess without seeing the declaration for `Cn`: bad connectionstring maybe? You shouldn't be caching the connection object, and should be disposing it and the adapter with `using` blocks

Comment: Thanks. Just copy the code and modify the code for my program, actually not an IT professional. For this example, how to convert it to using block?

Comment: Did you have a look at the details of the error message and inner messages?  What have you tried? Also Isolate the issue to see where its coming from by checking if its coming from ```Cn.Open()``` or any of the other ones. But yes make sure first your connection is valid and does open.

Comment: Connection is valid. I have attached screenshots in this question. When I open the application for first time, and I open a child form randomly, it works fine. But when I switch to another child form, it crushes with unhandled exception.

Comment: In the exception look if there is an InnerException and if yes, what is the message. Also, without seeing your query and what is your database is not possible to tell if there is some error in the query text that result in some weird exception

Comment: There are many places causing unhandled exception, here is one sample query: string sqlStr = "SELECT DISTINCT TeamName, Owner, Administrator from TableTeam WHERE Username ='" + Environment.UserName + "'  ORDER BY TeamName ASC";

Comment: Is the ODBC driver actually installed? Is this the first time you ran this on this PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify the `Platform target` to `x86` or `x64`, and then rebuild the project.

By the steps:

`Project` => `Properties` => `Build`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are opening  a connection before creating an adapter. Use this code:

```
 var sqlStr = "SELECT ......";
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (cn =
                new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OdbcDataAdapter adapt =
                new OdbcDataAdapter(sqlStr , cn))
        {
        
         adapt.Fill(dt);
         dgvABC.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try your method.